# Did I fry my arduino?

Tags: arduino

My brother while playing plugged my laptop's charger into arduino when it started smoking immediately i took the charger out. I had connected l298n motor driver also with it. What part of arduino is fried and is l298n motor driver fried too?
motor driver was connected to my motor dual axis joystick module was also connected to arduino. Are they all damaged? The motor driver led are still glowing and arduino's too. at the side of connector (circle one) the regulator like substance looks melted.

Comment: The blackened bit that emitted smoke is fried. Everything connected to it should be tested too.

Comment: The L298 is no great loss.

Comment: You really need to provide more information. Are we supposed to guess the voltage of the laptop charger, how it was connected to the arduino, how the motor driver was connected, etc? Maybe you could provide a photo of the damage (if it's visible?). Maybe you could try using the arduino and motor driver so that you can test if they work? I mean we don't have a crystal ball here, and we can't test it for you.

Comment: Laptop chargers are usually 19V~ish. Arduino is rated up to 12V or 16V I guess. Any of the following could have happened: 1) A sustainable current drawn by you motors at 12V became too much at 19V, frying something on the board. 2)Any of the circuitry expecting up to 12V~16V got fried when receiving 19V. Unlikely to happen so fast since its so close, but who knows.

Comment: The best case is that a large load on the 5v caused the regulator to try to supply a large current with a large input voltage, so let out the smoke, and go open circuit. If it failed short circuit, you can expect it to have trashed the rest of the board. Try powering up just the R3 from the USB, as that doesn't need the regulator.

Comment: *"What is wrong with my arduino uno r3"*  You mean other than being a arduino in the first place?

Comment: @OlinLathrop - Are you portraying a disdain for Arduinos in general or do I misunderstand?

Comment: motor driver was connected to my motor dual axis joystick module was also connected to arduino. Are they all damaged? The motor driver led are still glowing and arduino's too.

Answer (score 4):

Assume it's all toast, since much of it likely is.  Even the parts that aren't obviously charred could be damaged or will now fail soon under ordinary use.

Ditch it and don't look back.  Otherwise you'll just spend a lot of time with flaky results at best.